# Помощь в формировании регулярного выражения

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Имеется список строк, нужно регулярное выражение которое мне из списка ниже вернет иной список. Мне нужно из списка ниже вычленить текст после содержимого в квадратных скобках, если оно есть и текстом ";@" - если он есть.

Исходный список:

```
list_of_string = ["D.MM.YYYY;@", 
                  "[$-x-sysdate]DDDD, MMMM DD, YYYY",
                  "h:mm;@", 
                  "[$-x-systime]hh:mm:ss",
                  "DDDD, MMMM DD, YYYY hh:mm",
                  "DDDD, MMMM DD, YYYY hh:mm:ss", 
                  "D MMM;@", 
                  "MMMM YYYY"]
```

Список который я хочу получить.

```
list_string_after = ["D.MM.YYYY", 
                  "DDDD, MMMM DD, YYYY",
                  "h:mm", 
                  "hh:mm:ss",
                  "DDDD, MMMM DD, YYYY hh:mm",
                  "DDDD, MMMM DD, YYYY hh:mm:ss", 
                  "D MMM", 
                  "MMMM YYYY"]
```

Регулярное выражение, которое я написал:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r"^(?:\[.+\])?(.+)(?:\;@)?$")

for st in list_of_string:
    p = re.search(pattern, st)
    print(p)
```

Возвращает мне следующее:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 11), match='D.MM.YYYY;@'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 32), match='[$-x-sysdate]DDDD, MMMM DD, YYYY'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 6), match='h:mm;@'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 21), match='[$-x-systime]hh:mm:ss'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 25), match='DDDD, MMMM DD, YYYY hh:mm'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 28), match='DDDD, MMMM DD, YYYY hh:mm:ss'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 7), match='D MMM;@'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 9), match='MMMM YYYY'>
```

Как мне исправить регулярку, чтобы оно не захватывало последний знак собачки?

Comment: А у вас этот символ вне подмаски, попробуйте `print(p.group(1))`

Comment: Ну он же мне вернет сматченные строки. А они и так виды выше. Содержат в себе ";@".

Comment: Да, вам еще нужно поправить выражение на `pattern = re.compile(r"^(?:\[.+\])?(.*?)(?:;@)?$")` - https://rextester.com/YDALN69424

Comment: Супер, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

При использовании вашего подхода нужно ограничить "жадность" `.+`, иначе опциональный шаблон `(?:\;@)?` всегда будет находить пустую строку в конце.

Измените `.+` на `.*?`, нужное значение будет в первой группе (подмаске):

```
import re
list_of_string = ["D.MM.YYYY;@", 
                  "[$-x-sysdate]DDDD, MMMM DD, YYYY",
                  "h:mm;@", 
                  "[$-x-systime]hh:mm:ss",
                  "DDDD, MMMM DD, YYYY hh:mm",
                  "DDDD, MMMM DD, YYYY hh:mm:ss", 
                  "D MMM;@", 
                  "MMMM YYYY"]

pattern = re.compile(r"^(?:\[.+\])?(.*?)(?:;@)?$")

for st in list_of_string:
    p = re.search(pattern, st)
    print(p.group(1))
```

См. [пример работы кода онлайн](https://rextester.com/YDALN69424)